# Django Forms - object has no attribute 'request' error

Tags: python, django, search

I have a search form where I have an optional field `city_id`

My form:

```
class BusinessSearchForm(SearchForm):

def no_query_found(self):
    return self.searchqueryset.all()

def search(self):

    sqs = super(BusinessSearchForm, self).search()

    # if something goes wrong
    if not self.is_valid():
        return self.no_query_found()

    # filter search results 
    if 'city_id' in self.request.GET: # or POST
        sqs = sqs.filter(city_id=self.request.GET.get('city_id')) 
    else:
        sqs = sqs.filter(...)

    return sqs
```

This is the error I get:

`object has no attribute 'request' error`

Default Haystack SearchForm:

```
 class SearchForm(forms.Form):
q = forms.CharField(required=False, label=_('Search'),
                    widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'type': 'search'}))

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.searchqueryset = kwargs.pop('searchqueryset', None)
    self.load_all = kwargs.pop('load_all', False)

    if self.searchqueryset is None:
        self.searchqueryset = SearchQuerySet()

    super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def no_query_found(self):
    """
    Determines the behavior when no query was found.

    By default, no results are returned (``EmptySearchQuerySet``).

    Should you want to show all results, override this method in your
    own ``SearchForm`` subclass and do ``return self.searchqueryset.all()``.
    """
    return EmptySearchQuerySet()

def search(self):
    if not self.is_valid():
        return self.no_query_found()

    if not self.cleaned_data.get('q'):
        return self.no_query_found()

    sqs = self.searchqueryset.auto_query(self.cleaned_data['q'])

    if self.load_all:
        sqs = sqs.load_all()

    return sqs

def get_suggestion(self):
    if not self.is_valid():
        return None

    return self.searchqueryset.spelling_suggestion(self.cleaned_data['q'])
```

view.py

```
query = ''
results = EmptySearchQuerySet()

args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))

if request.GET.get('q'):
    form = form_class(request.GET, searchqueryset=searchqueryset,
                      load_all=load_all)

    if form.is_valid():
        query = form.cleaned_data['q']
        results = form.search()
else:
    form = form_class(searchqueryset=searchqueryset,
                      load_all=load_all)
....
```

Comment: No, the form doesn't have a request attribute. What makes you think it does?

Comment: Can you provide the import statement for the SearchForm class please?

Comment: @daniel Every time I added the `request` to the form, I got error `name 'request' is not defined`.

Comment: @justcompile It is a default Haystack form

Comment: @justcompile I added the search form to my OP

Comment: You see, the problem seems to be that `SearchForm` expects a parameter called `q`, and you are passing one called `city_id`. Take a look at your view.py.

Comment: I can see that. I guess the question is how do I pass both values?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the city_id to the form:

```
def search(self, city_id):
    ...

    sqs = sqs.filter(city_id=city_id) 
    ...
```

and use it like:

```
city_id = request.GET.get('city_id')
my_form.search(city_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are trying to run view-specific code in your form class. The form should only be concerned about validating the data. I assume you have a view function where this form is being instantiated, and from there the view should be the one making the query:

Try in your view:

```
query = ''
results = EmptySearchQuerySet()

args = {}
args.update(csrf(request))

posted_data = {'q': request.GET.get('city_id') }

form = form_class(posted_data, searchqueryset=searchqueryset, load_all=load_all)

if form.is_valid():
    results = form.search(request.GET.get('city_id'))
```

And in your form:

```
def search(self, city_id=None):

    sqs = super(BusinessSearchForm, self).search()

    if city_id is not None:
        sqs = sqs.filter(city_id=city_id)
    return sqs
```

Comment: This is a Haystack SearchForm and I can manually filter the results. If I write `sqs = sqs.filter(city_id=1)` I will get correct results for `city_id=1`. I just want to filter the city_id dynamically, that's all.

Comment: I understand that. What I am saying is that this form only provides you a building block on how to validate the search parameter. You still need to have a view, right? How is your Django view using this form?

Comment: I have added the view to my OP

Answer (score 0):

The error statement itself answer your question.You have to pass request to your **search** function. Try this :

```
def search(self,request):

sqs = super(BusinessSearchForm, self).search()

# if something goes wrong
if not self.is_valid():
    return self.no_query_found()

# filter search results 
if 'city_id' in self.request.GET: # or POST
    sqs = sqs.filter(city_id=self.request.GET.get('city_id')) 
else:
    sqs = sqs.filter(...)

return sqs
```

Comment: 1. This still won't work, "self.request" is never defined by the default form constructor
 2. Even if it *did* work, it is terrible design. Forms and views have completely separate concerns. Let us not teach poor practices to a beginner.

Comment: @lullis is correcct, it does not work, I tried that. You get `search() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)` error

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this is bad practise, you could extend the init method as per the following:

```
class BusinessSearchForm(SearchForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.searchqueryset = kwargs.pop('searchqueryset', None)
        self.load_all = kwargs.pop('load_all', False)

        if self.searchqueryset is None:
            self.searchqueryset = SearchQuerySet()

        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)

        super(SearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

And then whereever you're initialising BusinessSearchForm you pass in request as an additional kwarg:

```
if request.GET.get('q'):
    form = form_class(request.GET, searchqueryset=searchqueryset,
                      load_all=load_all, request=request)

if form.is_valid():
    query = form.cleaned_data['q']
    results = form.search()
else:
    form = form_class(searchqueryset=searchqueryset,
                  load_all=load_all, request=request)
```

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but we can avoid the `request` not found problem by splitting the code into views.py, right?

Comment: Absolutely! There are any number of potential methods on the answer thread, and as stated the code above isn't ideal in terms of encapsulation, but will get round the OP's issue with the missing attribute

Comment: I just couldn't get my into my head as to why there is a `search` method in the BusinessForm class, I am a newbie to Djano :)

Comment: @justcompile Thanks for the feedback. I'm trying to implement this solution but not sure if I'm doing the right thing. The first portion will go into my forms.py and the second goes to views right? That being said, if I still keep the original `def search(self) ...` in the BusinessSearchForm and just include your portion above my `def no_query_found(self) ...` I still get the same error `global name 'request' is not defined`. What am I missing?

Comment: It sounds like a different error this time (global name isn't defined rather than object doesn't have attribute). That would imply that the request object in the view isn't available, which could be an indentation issue...Are you using a Class based view or a method view?